# Why does backdrop-filter change the position of child elements

Tags: html, css

This is a situation I encountered

```css
#block1 {
    top: 0vh;
    height: 50vh;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    /*backdrop-filter: blur(10px);*/
}
#block2 {
    width: 50vw;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50vh;
    background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A blue block will appear at the bottom of the page.
But when I add `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);` to `#block1`,

```css
#block1 {
    top: 0vh;
    height: 50vh;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
#block2 {
    width: 50vw;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50vh;
    background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This blue box will appear at the top of the page.
This is where I am confused.

Why does changing the background-filter of the parent element change the position of the child element?

Is this a feature of css? (if yes, then why does css have this feature)